# Better way to parse "Description (tag)" to "Description, tag"

Tags: ruby

I have a text file with many 1000s of lines like this, which are category descriptions with the keyword enclosed in parentheses

```
Chemicals (chem) 
Electrical (elec)
```

I need to convert these lines to comma separated values like so:

```
Chemicals, chem
Electrical, elec
```

What I am using is this:

```
lines = line.gsub!('(', ',').gsub!(')', '').split(',')
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

for posterity, this is the full code (based on the answers)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'

csvfile = CSV.open('output.csv', 'w')
File.open('c:/categories.txt') do |f|
  f.readlines.each do |line|
    (desc, cat) = line.split('(')
    desc.strip!
    cat.strip!
    csvfile << [desc, cat[0,cat.length-1]]
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you using he split method at the end? that will actually create an array like `[description, keyword]`

Comment: @NeX  By creating an array, I can do a csvfile << lines, where csvfile is from CSV.open, that will take care of escaping everything.

Comment: @sawa you are right.  years of explaining things to beginners have put me in the habit of saying round brackets, curly brackets, angle brackets and square brackets.

Comment: @kinjal so you were not looking for a way ` to convert these lines to comma separated values like so:`. You were looking for a way of create an array of arrays like `[['Chemicals','chem'][Electrical,'elec']]`.

Comment: @NeX: not being an expert on ruby, I am creating an array so that it is easier to write out to a CSV file.  See completed example above.

Comment: @kinjal: That's better ;). I was not talking about the Ruby expertise, just pointing that the question was not matching your real needs.

Comment: @kinjal: I have added a cleaner solution above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
line.sub!(/ \((\w+)\)$/, ', \1')
```

The `\1` will be replaced with the first match of the given regexp (in this case it will be always the category keyword). So it will basically change the `(chem)` with `, chem`.

Let's create an example using a text file:

```
lines = []
File.open('categories.txt', 'r') do |file|
  while line = file.gets 
    lines << line.sub(/ \((\w+)\)$/, ', \1')
  end
end
```

Based on the question updates I can propose this:

```
require 'csv'

csv_file = CSV.open('output.csv', 'w')

File.open('c:/categories.txt') do |f| 
  f.each_line {|c| csv_file << c.scan(/^(.+) \((\w+)\)$/)}
end

csv_file.close
```

Comment: the code proposed given does not put a comma between Description and keyword.  But thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Ruby 1.9, you can do it in one method call:

```
str = "Chemicals (chem)\n"
mapping = { ' (' => ', ',
            ')'  => ''}

str.gsub(/ \(|\)/, mapping)  #=> "Chemicals, chem\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, a cleaner, more efficient, way to do it would be:

```
description, tag = line.split(' ', 2) # split(' ', 2) will return an 2 element array of
                                      # the all characters up to the first space and all characters after. We can then use
                                      # multi assignment syntax to assign each array element in a different local variable
tag = tag[1, (tag.length - 1) - 1] # extract the inside characters (not first or last) of the string
new_line = description << ", " << tag # rejoin the parts into a new string
```

This will be computationally faster (if you have a lot of rows) because it uses direct string operations instead of regular expressions.

Comment: @hundredwatt, speed was important.

Comment: spoken too soon.  There are words with spaces, like 'Dyes & Intermediates'.  I have modified the example to split at '(' and remove the last character from the first item and second item.

Comment: This is both less obvious and slower than using a regular expression.  When I tested it against "Chemicals (chem)" using Ruby 1.9, it takes more than twice as long as either NeX's or steenslag's solutions.

Comment: "This will be computationally faster (if you have a lot of rows) because it uses direct string operations instead of regular expressions." You need to be very careful making that assertion if you haven't run benchmarks to test. Ruby's regex in 1.9 is pretty fast; It's surprised me several times.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad, can you post your tests please?

Comment: @the Tin Man, Sure.  I'm not sure where to post them, though.  They don't seem like a separate answer, and I wonder whether it's polite to add that much stuff to @hundredwatt's answer.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @Wayne Conrad, Several times I've done benchmarks of solutions in the answers, and I'll put the test code and results in a separate answer. I think seeing how the testing is done, and how disparate the results can be, really helps people learn. Sometimes a minor variation can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

No need to manipulate the string. Just grab the data and output it to the CSV file.
Assuming that you have something like this in the data:

Chemicals (chem)

Electrical (elec)

Dyes & Intermediates (dyes)

This should work:

```
File.open('categories.txt', 'r') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    csvfile << line.match(/^(.+)\s\((.+)\)$/) { |m| [m[1], m[2]] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarks relevant to discussion in @hundredwatt's answer:

```
require 'benchmark'

line = "Chemicals (chem)"

# @hundredwatt
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times do
    description, tag = line.split(' ', 2)
    tag = tag[1, (tag.length - 1) - 1]
    new_line = description << ", " << tag
  end
} # => 0.18

# NeX
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times do
    line.sub!(/ \((\w+)\)$/, ', \1')
  end
} # => 0.08

# steenslag
mapping = { ' (' => ', ',
  ')'  => ''}
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times do
    line.gsub(/ \(|\)/, mapping)
  end
} # => 0.08
```

Answer (score -1):

know nothing about ruby, but it is easy in php

```
 preg_match_all('~(.+)\((.+)\)~','Chemicals (chem)',$m);

$result = $m[1].','.$m[2];
```